# How to use C# to determine if a certificate has been issued by the same CA as another?

Tags: c#, security, code-signing, x509certificate, x509

We are deploying an executable to a partner's site off our network.  The executable will dynamically load assemblies from a folder to perform certain tasks.

The executable will be signed and timestamped using a certificate issued by our CA.  I want to ensure that assemblies loaded by the executable have been signed by our CA.  How do I do this using C#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to compare [IssuerName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate2.issuername.aspx) properties of corresponding instances of X509Certificate2 class. Note that IssuerName is a reference to complex object whose properties must be inspected and compared.

Comment: This may be a dumb question, but as the IssuerName is just a string, what is stopping it being impersonated?

Comment: @SeanKearon IssuerName is not a string but an RDN (complex structure). IssuerName is part of the certificate which is signed. If you validate the certificate and find it valid, then you know that issuer name was not altered. Of course, certificate must be validated before you use it (and trust it).

Comment: I've just re-read your answer to my comment again.  Sorry to be a pain, but...what I meant to ask was not whether the cert had been tampered, but what is stopping someone setting up a CA with the same name as ours (CN = MyRootCA, DC = myDC, DC = net)?

Comment: @SeanKearon One way is to also check (a) Subject and Issuer names, and (b) serial numbers of CA certificates and up to the trusted root.

Answer (score -1):

There are several ways how an issuer is selected depending upon what is present in the certificate.
To sum up, these are Exact match, Key match, name match in order from more strict to less.

In Exact match, (AKI) authority key identifier extension is matched with the subject of the issuer. This AKI can contain issuer's name and serial.

In Key match, the AKI has only the hash of the pub key of the issuing certificate. The match involves only comparing the AKI with SKI of the issuing certificate.

The name match, if AKI is not present, is the least restrictive. Just compare the issuer name with the subject name of the issuing certificate.

As a recommendation, I suggest to atleast have AKI.